# java user input need printing without array

Tags: java, loops, user-input

Hey everyone I'm trying to get a user input to print over and over again. It is only printing the last user input I need to do this without a array. I have tried loops but I think that my knowledge is limited as I am fairly new to java if anyone can help that would be awesome

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String selection;
    String malesName = null; 
    double  malesAge = 0;
    String femalesName = null; 
    double femalesAge = 0; 
    do
    {
    System.out.println("Enter part Guests");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("\n");

    System.out.println("A - Male guest has arrived");
    System.out.println("B - Female Guest has arrived");
    System.out.println("X - There are no more guests");
    System.out.println("\n");

    System.out.println("Enter your selection:");
    selection = sc.nextLine();
        if (selection.length() !=1)
        {
            System.out.println("Response must be a single character!");
        }
        else
        {   
            switch (selection)
            {
               case "A":
               case "a":

                  System.out.print("Enter males name:");
                  malesName = input.nextLine();
                  System.out.print("Males ages:");
                  malesAge = input.nextDouble();
                  String input4 = input.nextLine();
                  break;
               case "B":
               case "b":
                  System.out.print("Enter females name:");
                  femalesName = input.nextLine();
                  String input5 = input.nextLine();
                  System.out.print("Females age:");
                  femalesAge = input.nextDouble();
                  String input6 = input.nextLine();
                  break;
               case "X":
               case "x":

                  System.out.println("Time to party...");
                  break;

               default:
                  System.out.println("Error - invalid selection!");

            }
         }




      } while (selection.equals("X") == false);



    String maleTotal =" - " + malesName + "(" + malesAge + ")"; 
    String femaleTotal = " - " + femalesName + "(" + femalesAge + ")" ;




    System.out.println("Male details:");
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.println( maleTotal );
    System.out.println("Female details:");
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print( femaleTotal );
/*
 * it should be printing
 * 
 * Male details:
 * -dan(22)
 * -sam(23)
 * Female details:
 * -samantha(32)
 * -julie(25)
 * 
 * 
 *but its only printing the last user input
 */


 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you only calculate the totals once because you have those statements after the loop ends. You should do the concatenation inside the loop and then to be able to print them later declare the variables before the loop starts.

```
String maleTotal = ""; 
String femaleTotal = "";

do {

    // rest of the code

    maleTotal += (" - " + malesName + "(" + malesAge + ")\n"); 
    femaleTotal += (" - " + femalesName + "(" + femalesAge + ")\n");

} while (!selection.equalsIgnoreCase("X"));
```

I would also suggest to switch to using `StringBuilder`s.

Comment: how come it prints the last string twice?im checking out stringbuilder now thanks :)

Comment: Maybe you forgot to remove the concatenation that's happening after the loop. It should happen only once and inside the loop. Then the number of entries would depend on the number of iterations the user requests for.

Comment: awesome I had stuff in the wrong place thank you so much

Comment: how would you suggest adding the ages I have tried
 maleAgeTotal = (malesAge + malesAge) but that didn't work  and I dunno what to google on it :/